# Maximum force of a metal ball going trough coil

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

I've been trying to figure out the maximum force of a metal ball going trough a coil.
I have:

$$ m=\chi_m V B \qquad B=N \mu_0 I R^2 \frac{1}{2(x^2+R^2)^{3/2}} $$

Also that $F=(m\cdot B)'$. However, since the maximum magnitude of the field happens in it's center, we have that $F_\text{center}=0$. I've tried using a limit argument but I still get 0.